# Simple Implementation of a ReentrantLock

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

An implementation of a ReentrantLock:

```
public class ReentrantLock {
    private boolean isLocked = false;
    private Thread lockedBy = null;
    private int lockCount = 0;

    public synchronized void lock() throws InterruptedException{
        while(isLocked && Thread.currentThread() != lockedBy){
            this.wait();
        }
        isLocked = true;
        lockedBy = Thread.currentThread();
        lockCount++;
    }

    public synchronized void unlock(){
        if(Thread.currentThread() == lockedBy){
            lockCount--;
        }
        if(lockCount == 0){
            isLocked = false;
            this.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code looks sensible, with two exceptions, the unlock should only notify when the lock is unlocked.... your code currently allows for asymmetrical notifications (excessive notifications).

Consider:

> ```
> public synchronized void unlock(){
>     if(Thread.currentThread() == lockedBy){
>         lockCount--;
>     }
>     if(lockCount == 0){
>         isLocked = false;
>         this.notify();
>     }
> }
> ```

The code above notifies even if nothing was locking things. The effect is probably minor, but it is important for classes like this to show symmetry. The code should be:

```
public synchronized void unlock(){
    if (!isLocked || lockedBy != Thread.currentThread()) {
        return;
    }
    lockCount--;
    if(lockCount == 0){
        isLocked = false;
        this.notify();
    }
}
```

A further vulnerability is that you leak the lock's monitor. Using synchronized methods is a problem, because someone can simply synchronize on your whole class, and deadlock the entire system.... Consider a thread that maliciously does:

```
synchronized (lockInstance) {
    Thread.sleep(10000000);
}
```

Now no other thread can lock, or unlock that instance, and will just hang.

You should instead use a private monitor:

```
private final Object sync = new Object();
```

and then synchronize on that:

```
synchronized (sync) {
   .....
}
```

Comment: If we check the current thread first and then do the rest of the operations, can't we drop the `synchronized` keyword completely?

Answer (score 0):

You can also get rid of the `isLocked` instance variable and replace the expression `isLocked` with `lockedBy != null`.

Combining this with @rofl's suggestions, I arrive at the following:

```
class ReentrantLock {
    private final Object sync = new Object(); // private monitor
    private Thread lockedBy = null;  // null => unlocked                        
    private int lockCount = 0;

    public void lock() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (sync) {
            Thread callingThread = Thread.currentThread();
            while (lockedBy != null && lockedBy != callingThread)
                wait();
            lockedBy = callingThread; // (re)locked!                            
            lockCount++;
        }
    }

    public void unlock() {
        synchronized (sync) {
            if (Thread.currentThread() == lockedBy)
                if (--lockCount == 0) {
                    lockedBy = null;      // unlocked!                          
                    notify();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dumping code isn't considered a review.

Comment: @topinfrassi I understand, yet I thought it would be nice to see a complete solution a result of previous comments -- at least that is what I was looking for originally.

Comment: @wcochran, thanks for the final version!